# Is it allowed to use this link (https://www.instagram.com/[username]/?__a=1)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

at the moment I am working on a Instagram implementation for the homepage of my school.
My problem was, that I didn’t got access to the account, so I couldn’t generate an access token (which all free joomla plugins need).
So I have decided to write my own plugin (I am not the best programmer, but it works), because of that I found this link (https://www.instagram.com/[username]/?__a=1) where I could get the JSON of the public page without the need of any token or ID.

My question is if I am allowed to use it or not (because I can’t find this link in the official api)?

Comment: This does not seem to work as of today returns a HTTP 403 to me.

Comment: Yes it was changed a few days ago. ATM I am working on another solution.

Comment: @DaKi0709 let us know if u get a working solution

Comment: It is working as of today april 16  Again.. wish they leave it intact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've built a small API that scrapes exactly that data and presents it to you via JSON:

`https://apinsta.herokuapp.com/u/<username>`

(In case you are still interested in this)

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was searching for. Can you explain me how it scrapes the data from Instagram (if it isn‘t a secret) because I am very interested in things like these? And please also tell me if i have to mention you and how If i use the link for a Instagram implementation.

Comment: We actually fetch the instagram page of that account in which the data is embedded. Then - with the help of some RegExp magic, we filter the data and present it to you. There is some caching involved to not stress the IG page too much. :-)

Comment: RIP `apinsta`. I will miss this great little service. Please open-source, @Sebastian!

Answer (score 1):

This URL closed by instagram on 14 April. You can get user's information json with this link:

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USER_ID/info/

Also you can find user ID like this:

Go to the https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/

Look source code and find this code:

```
"id":"
```

You'll see the user ID between quotes.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I have tried it and i got the profilepicture and some other informations but is there a way to modify the link to get the posts (pictures and text)?

Comment: Yes, you can get profile picture dp and hd version. If this solution helped of you please vote it.

Comment: Yes you can find also posts information there without secret profiles. No way to find for secret profiles. Only you can find profile picture dp and hd version for secret profiles.

Comment: If i use for example the Coca-Cola page (https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/249655166/info/) (i have found in the json file that it‘s a public page) how can i get the json data of the last posts not only the profile picture and the username?

Comment: I think also changed this api URL by Instagram I did not know that. But look to the source page https://www.instagram.com/cocacola there is many information about posts, I'd and others. Only you can not find profile picture hd version.

Comment: Ok i will try to get the data of the source page but i have tried it a view months ago. Back then I couldn‘t get anything from that page because they are protecting it (for example they block iFrames and things like that)